# How to enable reverse proxy but block direct access to port 8080 in Nginx and CherryPy?

Tags: python, nginx, reverse-proxy, cherrypy

I have running Nginx and uwsgi on my Linux box but I have to port my code to Windows. So I have selected CherryPy to rewrite my code but I have problem because I don't know how to block direct access to CherryPy port 8080 and still enable reverse proxy in Nginx.

Here's my config

nginx:

```
upstream apps {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.htm index.html index.nginx.html;

    server_name localhost;

    merge_slashes off;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;

    location / {

        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        proxy_pass        http://apps;
        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

And here's my Cherrypy config:

```
_config = {
    'global' : {
        # http server
        'server.socket_host' : "127.0.0.1",
        'server.socket_port' : 8080,
        'server.thread_pool' : 8,
        # file change reload
        'engine.autoreload_on' : False,
        # url trailing slash
        'tools.trailing_slash.on' : False,
        # logging
        'log.access_file' : os.path.join(_path, "variable/log/access_back.log"), 
        'log.error_file'  : os.path.join(_path, "variable/log/error_back.log"),
    },
    '/' : {
        'tools.encode.encoding' : "utf-8"
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I've discovered that I have linked wrong neginx config in sites-enabled, that's why I could access 8080 from my lan. My big bad :( Afterr I've corrected this, both of these configurations are working for me, so I've had the answer from start.

Comment: Setting host to `127.0.0.1` should make it only accessible from localhost. Have you tried accessing the port from remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

This `'server.socket_host' : "127.0.0.1",` says that CherryPy already listens only your loopback interface and won't serve connection on other interfaces. In other words it is only accessible on port 8080 from the machine it is running on.

Comment: ITnx saaj, I've used that config from your webapp. And I'm a shamed to say that I have linked wrong config file in sites-enabled in my nginx and that was the reason why I could access 8080 directly from other computers on my lan. My bad.

Comment: @DamirPrebeg Yes, I've noticed that comments look familiar :-) No problem.